# Golang CSV error bare " in non-quoted-field

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, go

I haven't had trouble parsing csv files for my GAE golang app until this week (I updated to appengine 1.9.23 last week).  Now, regardless of file content I am getting this error:

2015/07/09 15:25:34 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:50352: line 1, column 22: bare " in non-quoted-field

Even when the file content doesn't contain any " characters at all the error occurs.

Anyone know why my files can no longer be parsed?  Something changed or I'm doing something super-stupid.

PS using urlfetch to obtain the csv file

Comment: Without sharing your code, helping will be tricky. A sample of the file that's causing the problem would likely help as well.

Answer (score 24):

This happens when we have on CSV file de `"` (double quotes) value.
To avoid this error we should use LazyQuotes Parameter like that:

```
csvFile, _ := os.Open("file.csv")
reader := csv.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(csvFile))
reader.Comma = ';'
reader.LazyQuotes = true
```

Answer (score 1):

If the csv decode library follows [RFC-4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2)

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.

For example:

```
"aaa","b""bb","ccc"
```

Answer (score 0):

After much ado I determined that the hosting company had updated DotDefender which introduced a rule to block .csv/.tsv     arg